# How to calculate the eigenvalues for a high-dimension matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix A, A = I- $X_n (X_n^T X_n)^{-1} X_n^T$, where $X_n$ is a $n \times p$ matrix.

And there is a condition such as the smallest eigenvalue of $X_n^T X_n$ is greater than a positive constant M.

How can I calculate the eigenvalues of matrix A; moreover, the eigenvalues of matrix A are between 0 and 1 ??

Answer (score 2):

Check that your matrix is an orthogonal projection. An orthogonal projection has only eigenvalues zero and one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the definition of orthogonal project. Thanks again.

Comment: You will have to check that $A^T = A$ and $A^2 = A$.

Comment: I can figure out $A^T$ =A, but I cannot figure out $A^2$ = A. Which formula should I use?

Comment: No formula to use. Just check.